# Sending an MMS to an existing group chat

Tags: twilio, sms, mms

MMS messages from group chats include multiple long code numbers (a.k.a. phone numbers) in the 'to' field. What APIs allow you to read multiple phone numbers from an incoming message and to then respond to the group chat?

Twilio does not support this user story, or at least I couldn't figure out how to use it in this way.